# DocusignAPI review

Tags: postman, docusignapi

After I made 25 (only 20 are needed and all were successful) requests, using postman, I submitted for review in the docusign page APPS AND KEYS, but it came back with an error saying:

> Error calls detected.

What could be wrong?

In each test do I have to wait 15min between requests? Could that avoid my error?
Should I have some different content for each API call?

In postman there is no error and in the docusign there are only successful requests so I don't understand where there can be an error.

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was just a Docusign error as I restarted the process from the beginning and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're required to use your application (not Postman) to make the API calls used by the Go-Live review process.

Download the Go-Live report to see which calls Go-Live was monitoring and which was perceived to be an error

Also, the Go-Live test uses your last set of calls. Perhaps you made an error call after the good calls.

Re: 15 min period -- you're not allowed to poll for an object's status more often than once every 15 minutes. For API calls which are not polling the system: you can make them as fast as you want, up to a limit of [500 calls per 30 second period](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/resource-limits/)

Comment: It didn´t work for me. This error continues and i realised that even though the call is successfull, it has a "Response Type: failed". What could cause this?

Comment: Use the DocuSIgn [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus&language=en_US&rsc_301) feature to capture the log of the problematic API call. Then ask a NEW question on StackOverflow if you can't figure it out on your own. Remove any private info from the log before posting it in a question.